# Check if Cassandra is working

Tags: java, cassandra

I am a newbie to Cassandra and I am tring to write test cases to cassandra with JUnit. 
I use CassandraDaemon class to start cassandra in IntelliJ IDEA. I want to wait 
until Cassandra up and running before runnig test methods. Is there any way to check if cassandra is running (with Java)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Occasionally I have such code:

```
    DatabaseDescriptor.createAllDirectories();
    CassandraDaemon cassandraDaemon = new CassandraDaemon();
    cassandraDaemon.init(null);
    cassandraDaemon.start();
```

Once you run it you can be sure that Cassandra is up and running. Method `start()` is blocking. Once it returns Cassandra is running.

Comment: thanks @AlexR I did not know that start() method is blocking. You saved  my some time.